# Modify values to concatenate binary text data

Tags: python

This topic is basically based on *concatenation (of iterable data)*  or another such data type as `list`. In order to make *printable representation*, **`built-in`** [**`repr`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) returns an **array** *object* **strong text** containing single quotes next to opposite quotes, then, contain some method associated with **repr** or the method used by a previous statement such as **join** for the next expression `map(lambda x: repr("".join(list(' '*10))), range(12))` and then use as a parameter in the **list()** method, like the following example.

Could you remove the quote characters that are only located at indices in the index range `[-2:] [2:]`?

```py
# example number N for range
map(lambda x: repr("".join(list(' '*10))), range(12))
>>> <map object at 0x00000240540F4640>
list(map(lambda x: repr("".join(list(' '*10))), range(12)))
["'          '", "'          '", "'          '", 
 "'          '", "'          '", "'          '",
 "'          '", "'          '", "'          '",
 "'          '", "'          '", "'          '"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify

`map(lambda x: repr("".join(list(' '*10))), range(12))`

to this

`map(lambda x: repr("".join(list(' '*10)))[2:-2], range(12))`

here is full code

```
>>> k = map(lambda x: repr("".join(list(' '*10)))[2:-2], range(12))
>>> list(k)
['        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ', '        ']
```

Comment: your answer indicates what i mentioned about indexing values and omitting quotes but when i try to do for example `val = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], val[2] = '1000'`, and then `"".join(val)` using **repr** and **map** i see erroneous results, i was expecting other options apart of the *index* assignation

Comment: you need to check `str` methods they might help you

Comment: ok it's fixed, so I was incorrectly using the **join** method along with **repr**

Comment: yeah you just need to use it with `__repr__` in class method or just during debuging